# How to patch a typescript declaration file to export an UMD global?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, type-declaration

Say I have download a typing file for module `XXX`, it doesn't write `export as namespace XXX`. But actually in its js file, it export the global variable `XXX`.

So how I can emulate the typging file just like it write the `export as namespace XXX`. A typical method is to write something like:

```js
delcare global
{
    export var XXX: typeof import('XXX');
}
```

But this doesn't export the namespace `XXX`.

I can use XXX as a variable.

```js
var x = XXX.createSomething();
```

But I can't use it as namespace.

```js
var x: XXX.ISomething = XXX.createSomething();
```